# Need to return a python-made webpage, without waiting for a subprocess to complete

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, html, popen

OK so I am trying to run one python script (test1.py) and print something into a webpage at the end. I also want a subprocess (test2.py) to begin during this script. However, as it happens, test2.py is going to take longer to execute than test1. The problem that I am having is that test1.py is being held up until test2 completes. I have seen numerous people post similar questions but none of the solutions I've seen have fixed my issue.

Here's a heavily simplified version of my code that demonstrates the issue. I am running it on a local server, and displaying it in firefox.

test1.py:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import subprocess

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

print("Content-Type: text/html") # HTTP header to say HTML is following
print                          # blank line, end of headers

p = subprocess.Popen(['python','test2.py'])

print "script1 ended"
```

test2.py:

```
from time import sleep

print "script2 sleeping...."
sleep(60)
print "script2 ended"
```

Essentially I want to execute test1.py and have it say "script1 ended" in firefox, without having to wait 60 seconds for the subprocess to exit. I don't want anything from the test2 subprocess to show up.

EDIT: For anyone interested.. I solved the problem in windows by using os.startfile(), and as it turns out subprocess.Popen([...], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) works in Linux. The scripts run in the background without delaying anything in the parent script when I do a wget on it.

Comment: It works locally if you [add `sys.stdout.flush()` where necessary](https://gist.github.com/zed/46a210950c95f73a75a6).

Comment: Thanks. I'd tried that but it didn't seem to work for me.
I did find a solution though; I had to use os.startfile('test2.py'). It's not perfect as I'm not able to pass any arguments to it (which I may need later), and also I think it only works on windows. But it'll do for now. If you have any suggestions as to why flush() isn't working for me I'd be happy to hear them!